# Distância entre LI's na vertical

Tags: css, css3

```css
ul.ulVertical {
 border: .1px rgb(0, 0, 0) solid;
 list-style: none;
 width: 800px;
 height: 100px;
}

ul.ulVertical li {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100px;
 height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 border-top: .1px rgb(0, 0, 0) solid;
 transform: rotate(270deg);
 transform-origin: top right;
}

ul.ulVertical li:last-chield {
 border: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ulVertical">
 <li>Passo 1</li>
 <li>Passo 2</li>
 <li>Passo 3</li>
 <li>Passo 4</li>
 <li>Passo 5</li>
 <li>Passo 6</li>
 <li>Passo 7</li>
 <li>Passo 8</li>
 <li>Passo 9</li>
 <li>Passo 10</li>
 <li>Passo 11</li>
 <li>Passo 12</li>
 <li>Passo 13</li>
</ul>
```

Esse código funciona.

Mas devido à **largura** na **horizontal** da `li` ser de `100px`, isso leva a um distanciamento entre as `li's` de tamanho igual ao de sua largura na horizontal.

***O que eu preciso?***

Arranjar uma forma de aproximar as `li's` de uma **forma** que não haja **espaço** entre elas quando estiverem na **vertical**.

Comment: Não está muito claro o que você deseja.

Comment: Não poderia retirar o width? O problema é que a UL tem 800px de largura e cada LI tem 100px, e como são 13 LI's, vai ultrapassar a largura da UL.

Comment: bom, esses 100px da li é para que as li's tenha a altua compativel com a UL. Senão, a LI vai ficar pequena dento da UL. Algum recurso à isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue uma opção, mas vc vai precisar colocar o texto que está dentro da `<li>` em um `<span>`.

Dessa forma vc rotaciona o texto dentro da `LI` e não a `LI` em si. Isso vai te dar mais controle das coisas.

```css
ul.ulVertical {
  border: .1px rgb(0, 0, 0) solid;
  list-style: none;
  width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.ulVertical li {
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  float: left;
  border-left: 1px rgb(0, 0, 0) solid;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
ul.ulVertical li span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: max-content;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

```html
<ul class="ulVertical">
  <li><span>Passo 1</span></li>
  <li><span>Passo 2</span></li>
  <li><span>Passo 3</span></li>
  <li><span>Passo 4</span></li>
  <li><span>Passo 5</span></li>
  <li><span>Passo 6</span></li>
  <li><span>Passo 7</span></li>
  <li><span>Passo 8</span></li>
  <li><span>Passo 9</span></li>
  <li><span>Passo 10</span></li>
  <li><span>Passo 11</span></li>
  <li><span>Passo 12</span></li>
  <li><span>Passo 13</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: pois é, mas eu preciso também juntar essas li's uma às outras de forma tal que a separação seja apenas a borda. Essa borda também precisa ser de toda altura da li e uma última observação é que as li's precisam tomar todo o width da UL

Comment: @CarlosRocha fiz uma edição na resposta, executa e olha ai se ficou mais de acordo

Comment: Oi, é exatamente isso. Mas eu possuo uma certo afinidade com display: in li-ne block e não com  flex. Seria pedir demais uma solução que não envolva 
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  float: left;
  flex-grow: 1;? Se não der, vou saber entender. Mas de qualquer forma, pelo seu esforço vou aceitar a resposta!

Comment: @CarlosRocha o que acontece é que o inline-block não faz tudo que o flex faz, como o nome diz o flex é flexível, coisa que o inline-block não é. O flex meio que automaticamente divide os itens em tamanhos iguais, com inline-block isso não é possível... Se o seu problema em usar o Flex é apenas pq vc não tem familiaridade como ele é só vc ir no Youtube e ver uns tutoriais, em 30 min vc vai ficar fera em Flex. []´s

Comment: na verdade as lis não tem mesmo os mesmos tamanhos. Cada uma abrigará um tipo de dado. Teria que em cada li definir manualmente seus widths

Comment: Entendi, então é só ir colocando na mão já que cada um tem um tamanho

Comment: é mais o dificil pra mim está sendo retirar o display; flex

Comment: @CarlosRocha aqui tem um vídeo de menos de 20 min pra vc aprender FlexBox em português  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dbVQqcV9iEc

Answer (score 0):

Converta a `ul` em *flexbox* e use `flex-basis: 100px;` (onde o valor `100px` é um valor que irá acomodar as `li`'s dentro da `ul`, pois o `flex-basis` permite redução caso a soma de todas as larguras `li`'s ultrapasse a `ul`).

É preciso também que as `li`'s possuam `position: relative` para o `left: -50px;` funcionar. Retire também o padding da `ul` para ficar melhor distribuído:

```css
ul.ulVertical {
 border: .1px rgb(0, 0, 0) solid;
 list-style: none;
 width: 800px;
 height: 100px;
   display: flex;
   padding: 0;
}

ul.ulVertical li {
   position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 /* width: 100px; */
 height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 border-top: .1px rgb(0, 0, 0) solid;
 transform: rotate(270deg);
   flex-basis: 100px;
 transform-origin: top right;
   left: -50px;
}

ul.ulVertical li:last-chield {
 border: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ulVertical">
 <li>Passo 1</li>
 <li>Passo 2</li>
 <li>Passo 3</li>
 <li>Passo 4</li>
 <li>Passo 5</li>
 <li>Passo 6</li>
 <li>Passo 7</li>
 <li>Passo 8</li>
 <li>Passo 9</li>
 <li>Passo 10</li>
 <li>Passo 11</li>
 <li>Passo 12</li>
 <li>Passo 13</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nota que existe um espaço entre a margem do Passo 1 e a borda da UL. Isso deve estar ocorrendo porque as li's não estão ocupando todo o espaço da UL. Outro problema aí é o tamanho da borda e também da li que devem te a altura a UL